# Scraping with selenium to run a script

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to **scrape** a website that runs a this script

```
    <div id="premarket_container" style="min-height: 250px;">
                 </div>
                 <script>
                    $(window).load(function () {
                        nativo_DynamicContentLoaded();
                    });
                 </script>
```

but Selenium won't run it so I can't get the information I need.

Can someone help me, I am new to python.

Comment: Did you using getAttribute property

Comment: Please add your python code so we can help correct it.

Comment: Refer this https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/web-scraping-using-python

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that Selenium is running it, but only after you execute your scraping code. `$(window).load` is essentially code which says **once** the page has loaded **then** load the data.

The problem is that Selenium is very likely executing the code you want it to before that function has time to finish. You will probably be needing [this documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you Matthew, this makes sense and I understand why it would work, but I tried to make it wait, but the issue is that when Selenium run and the browser opens and loads the website the the script does not run and the data I need is not loaded   in the browser?

Comment: The website is https://marketchameleon.com/Reports/PremarketTrading

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Python\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://marketchameleon.com/Reports/PremarketTrading')

#res = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
#driver.quit()
#time.sleep (20)
#soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
#box = soup.find('div', {'id': 'gainers_outer '})
#print(box)

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((Byu.ID, "gainers_outer")))

finally:
    drvice.quit()
```